# Error in \cite question mark, but entry is showing in bibliography

Tags: latex, bibtex, overleaf

I am using overleaf. I am writing an article using article document class. I use school.sty file to modify certain styles.
In my article, I need to cite a few references. So I created research.bib.

When I include \cite{einstein} in the tex file, I get a question mark, whereas there is an entry for the einstein after compilation.

```
[1] Albert Einstein. Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K ̈orper. (German) [On the electrodynam-
ics of moving bodies]. Annalen der Physik, 322(10):891–921, 1905.
```

Can someone please help me to resolve the question mark error when using \cite{}.

This is my main.tex

```
% % document type % %
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% % preamble % %
\usepackage{amsmath} % % centers and provides equation numbers for align env
\usepackage{amssymb} % % allows use of normal N symbol
\usepackage{graphicx} % % allows graphics floats
\usepackage{grffile} % % allows more image file names
\usepackage{subcaption} % % allows subfigures in floats
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % % allows URLs and in-document hyperlinking
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace} % % allows line spacing
\usepackage{moreverb} % % allows use of verbatimtab
\renewcommand\verbatimtabsize{4\relax} % % sets verbatimtab indent to half of default, looks better
\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip} % % don't indent new paragraphs
\restoreparindent
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{harvard}


 % header and footer % %
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead[L]{Research Statement}  % left header
    \fancyhead[R]{\Name{}} % right header
    
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % % pg number in footer
    \fancyfoot[C]{} % % remove default centered page numbers
    \fancyfoot[L]{} % last compiled in footer
}

% % expand head of document:
\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}

% % application specific information % %
\usepackage{school}

% % document begins % %
\begin{document} \pagestyle{plain}

% % body % %

My research interest \cite{einstein}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{research}

\end{document}
```

My research.bib file

```
@article{einstein,
    author = "Albert Einstein",
    title = "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal = "Annalen der Physik",
    volume = "322",
    number = "10",
    pages = "891--921",
    year = "1905",
    DOI = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
    keywords = "physics"
}
```

This is my school.sty file

```
% % color for links
\definecolor{linkcol}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.3}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,
    linkcolor=linkcol,urlcolor=linkcol,
    anchorcolor=linkcol,citecolor=linkcol}

% For \email{ADDRESS}, links ADDRESS to the url mailto:ADDRESS in teletype fixed-width font
\providecommand*\email[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{\texttt{#1}}}

% For \url{ADDRESS}, links ADDRESS to the url https://ADDRESS in teletype fixed-width font
\renewcommand*\url[1]{\href{http://#1}{\texttt{#1}}}

% % use for commenting -- change initials to match yours
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\rwcomment}[1]{{\textcolor{blue}{\textsc{\textbf{[#1 --RW]}}}}}

% % document variables % %

% % your name
\newcommand{\Name}{SUMESH}

% % position name
\newcommand{\PositionName}{TITLE position in SUBFIELD}

% % institution name
\newcommand{\InstitutionName}{SCHOOL}

% % department name
\newcommand{\DepartmentName}{DEPTARTMENT}

% % department address
\newcommand{\DepartmentAddress}{ROOM BUILDING \\
    STREET ADDRESS \\
    CITY STATE ZIP}
```

Comment: The question mark does not mean there is an error. It means that you need to rerun the LaTeX processor to allow it to recompute the page numbers correctly. This is normal: to compute page numbers for references, LaTeX routinely needs to be run several times. The processor output will tell you whether you have to rerun it.